# How to update a property file?

Tags: java, properties

i am using the classLoader method to load a property file. Using this, I am able to retrieve the values of properties but now I want to update the values of some properties and i am not able to do it. Please help. Here, is the code:

InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
  .getResourceAsStream("PublishDate.properties");

```
try {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
       // load the inputStream using the Properties
       properties.load(inputStream);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // get the value of the property
    String propValue = properties.getProperty("lastHtlProcessPublishDate");
```

here, in propValue i get the right value from file. I am updating this like this:

```
properties.put("lastHtlProcessPublishDate",dateFormatter.format(new Date()));   
properties.store(new FileOutputStream("PublishDate.properties"), null);
```

Using this the value doesn't get update but when i provide the complete path for `PublishDate.properties` then it works.
But, I don't want to give the complete path as the path is dynamic. Does someone knows how to do this using some relative path. Please advise me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try  [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/index.html) and use a PropertiesConfiguration. That should satisfy all your needs.

Comment: final AbstractFileConfiguration fileConfiguration = new PropertiesConfiguration( "PublishDate.properties" );
fileConfiguration.setProperty( "lastHtlProcessPublishDate", dateFormatter.format ( new Date() ) );
fileConfiguration.save();

Answer (score 4):

Use [Apache's Commons Configuration API](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/index.html) to handle your properties file. It will make reading and writing to property files(any configuration files)...and your life easier.

#### EDIT

- Download the commons-configuration binary [here](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/download_configuration.cgi)
- Place that somewhere in your classpath(`lib` directory if your project has one)
- Run a clean and build of your project so Eclipse(I'm assuming) can pick up the new classes
- Import the required classes for your action and code away. :D

Comment: Hi,i updated my code:PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("PublishDate.properties");                 config.setProperty("lastHtlProcessPublishDate",dateFormatter.format(new Date()) );
config.save();
but I am getting this on console: Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration
 at com.galileo.localdata.servlets.MVSDataServlet.run(MVSDataServlet.java:176)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration

Comment: Did you import the PropertiesConfiguration class? 
That is what that error means.

Comment: yes i imported the class and have also placed the jars for the same

Comment: Then Run a `clean` and `build` of your project so Eclipse(I'm assuming) can pick up the new classes

Comment: Done but still getting the same error.Earlier i was getting The type org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files. So, to fix this, I added commons-lang-exception-2.0.jar to build path. Is this error occuring because of this?